# What does ingrowth mean exactly?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The definition states:

> The act of growing inward or into.

So "vegetable ingrowth" can mean vegetables or part of a vegetable that grew into a hole? What are the other meaning that "growing inward" can mean, can it also mean inward of a deliminated area?

> In the lime stone in the upper portion of the section there was
>   originally an elaborate model of a Lead Mine, now obliterated with
>   white wash; and at the present time the beds and bands of coal are
>   disintegrated and destroyed by the ingrowth of vegetables.
>
> <sup>Source: [How the ‘Seven Deadly Agents of Destruction’ 
>   can help preserve the 
>   Crystal Palace Dinosaurs](https://cpdinosaurs.org/pdf/brierly-et-al-preprint.pdf)</sup>

I am not sure what's meant by model of a lead mine, but they probably mean a real lead mine and that the ingrowth of vegetables grew into the cave and disintegrated and destroyed the beds and bands of coal.

Comment: Please give us the link to that text, if you have one. limestone is a single word. Is this a comment from a technical site? If so, is it geology or mining? Finally, I think they mean **vegetation** and not vegetables. [ha ha]

Comment: That is a quote, and it comes from 1874, a fact you failed to mention. Just saying....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vegetation in-growth = growth of vegetation is areas such as lakes or forests. It means growing in lakes or forest and is a noun. In other words, the vegetation is growing "inwards" in the site, not spreading out of it.

Active fire suppression has led to extreme fuel loading and vegetation in-growth throughout Syilx/Okanagan Territory, Glaser said.

[climate change](https://www.vernonmorningstar.com/news/collaborating-with-first-nations-in-b-c-to-combat-climate-change/)

In the quote above, it just means: vegetation growing in an area.

The term is from forestry and forestry management:

> Vegetation in-growth. This report assumes that in-growth is managed
>   with regular treatment (e.g., with herbicides) that limits in-growth.
>   If in-growth is allowed and fire is suppressed, estimates of carbon
>   pools on-site may significantly increase, especially for longer time
>   periods.
>
> [...] Simulate the effects on carbon pools and fire after either
>   natural seedling in-growth or planting in the understory.
>
> It means vegetation growing in the space between trees in forests. It is said to "grow in". Grow in between other things.

[in-growth_native English](https://www.nrdc.org/sites/default/files/ene_13041704a.pdf)

At a coastal site, large-scale climate variations affect the shoreline
displacement as well as the development and in-growth (sediment infilling and
vegetation in-growth) of lakes.

[from the Swedish but the term is right and so the paper's English](https://pub.epsilon.slu.se/14530/1/lindborg_t_170830.pdf)

algae bloom is an example of vegetation in-growth in a lake, if algae is considered vegetation, which I think it is.